# Closed form of :$\int_{-1}^1 x^{2k} (\operatorname{erf}(x))^k \,dx $ for $ k$ is even integer and :$\int _{0}^{t}\exp(-x^2 \operatorname{erf}(x))dx$

Tags: probability-distributions, integration, orthogonal-polynomials, closed-form-expressions

This question is related to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803363/behavior-of-int-ll-x2k-operatornameerfxk-dx) such that i want to find a closed form of  $\int_{-1}^1 x^{2k} (\operatorname{erf}(x))^k \,dx $ , for $k$ is even integer because for odd integer is $0$ as we have integrand of odd function , Really for $k=2$ it gives a nice closed form as shown [here in wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(+x%5E(4)+erf(x)%5E2)),+x%3D-1+to+1), Now my question here is :

> > **Question:**
> >     Is it possible to get a Closed form of  :$\int_{-1}^1 x^{2k} \operatorname{erf}(x)^k \,dx $ for $ k$  is even integer?

**Note:** The Motivation of this question is to find a Series representation of 
 :$\int _{0}^{t}\exp(-x^2 \operatorname{erf}(x))dx$

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: since $1$ and $-1$ are not spacial points for the integrand, his definite integral is likely just as difficult as the indefinite integral.  So: $\int x^4 \text{erf}(x)^2 dx$ has a known closed form, plug in and get your definite integral.  But for $\int x^8 \text{erf}(x)^4 dx$ you are probably out of luck.

Comment: What for? Isn't it art for art's sake?

Comment: No, it is not art for art's sake.

Comment: @Liviu Nikolaescu: Please, base your  statement.

Comment: @user64494, Probably Liviu Nicolaescu think that is easy for evaluation

Comment: @user64494 I think it is a  legitimate question.  "Art for art's sake" would suggest  this is  a useless question. I don't think it is.

Comment: @Liviu Nicolaescu: I prefer arguments over unbased words. Sorry, I have nothing to discuss with you in such manner.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu, have you tried out to see the behavior of that function  comparing it with error function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand from the OP that the motivation for this question is to find a series expansion in powers of $t$ of 
$$I(t)=\int _{0}^{t}\exp(-x^2 \operatorname{erf}(x))dx=\sum_{p=1}^\infty c_p t^p.$$
The coefficients $c_p=p^{-1}d_{p-1}$ follow from the series expansion
$e^{-x^2\,{\rm erf}\,x}=\sum_{p=0}^\infty d_p x^p$, resulting in
$$I(t)=\sum_{p=1}^\infty c_p t^p=t-\frac{t^4}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}+\frac{t^6}{9 \sqrt{\pi }}+\frac{2 t^7}{7 \pi }-\frac{t^8}{40 \sqrt{\pi }}-\frac{4 t^9}{27 \pi }+\frac{(\pi -28) t^{10}}{210 \pi ^{3/2}}+O\left(t^{11}\right).$$
The series $I(1)=\sum_{p=1}^\infty c_p$ seems to converge:

[image]

Plot of $I_N=\sum_{p=0}^{N} c_p $ as a function of $N$ up to $N=25$. The value of $I_{25}=0.8162$ agrees with $I(1)=0.816377$ to three decimal places. For $N=50$ the agreement is up to six decimal places.

Comment: But is it possible to get it for n th term  and it's seems that is a formel power series ?

Comment: The value of I(50) from wolfram alpha is : 0.972107 , https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(+exp(-x%C2%B2+erf(x)),+x%3D0+to+50&wal=header

Comment: @zeraouliarafik -- when I say $I_{50}=0.816377$ I am referring to the sum $I_{N}=\sum_{p=0}^N c_p$, which is the series expansion of $I(t)$ for $t=1$ to order 50; what you have evaluated with Wolfram alpha is $I(t)$ for $t=50$, which is a different thing.

Comment: I'm confused how you calculated the coeffecients of series using error function ?